# How to add a title to a section in a UITableView?

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview

I have looked all over the show but cannot find how to simply define my own section title.. So far I have tried this.

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 20; 
}
```

from what I have read these are the two delegate you need to add your own title.. so I am woundering what goes in the tableView:viewForHeaderInSection:

I have tried

```
if (section == 0){
   return @"header one";
}
```

but that didn't cut the mustard.. any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Just to add as a side note: You are returning a string while viewForHeaderInSection suppose to return -(UIView *)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you just want a title, override this method in UITableViewDataSource, rather than the two you have mentioned above.

```
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

Comment: what value we have to return in it if we don't use any label for header in section i tried this it shows an error "Control may reach end of non-void function"

Answer (score 3):

Following will help you out.

```
    - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
         return 1;
    }
    - (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section 
    {
         UIView *av=[[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 22)]  autorelease];
         NSString * weekdayString = [self getDayFromDate:testDate];
         UILabel *lblStr = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(40, 2, 100, 20)];
         lblStr.text = @"header one";
         lblStr.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
         lblStr.textColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
         lblStr.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:15];
         [av addSubview:lblStr];
         [lblStr release];     
    }
    - (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableViewheightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
         return 40;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

Expects you to return a object that is a UIView, such as a UIView itself or something like a UILabel.

So what you could do is return a UILabel which then contains your header. Example:

```
UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] init];
[label setText:@"Section 0"];
[label autorelease];
return label;
```

Alternatively you could style up a whole view in the interface builder and alloc, init and return that.

**If you're looking for just basic text, then gamozzii's answer is what you are looking for.**

Comment: Thank you.. so say for instance if you would like an image or a button in your header to the right of the section, you would do something like creating your own view then calling it from that delegate method...?

Comment: Yep you could build a new UIView in code, add your subviews (such as a right frame aligned UILabel) and then return the new UIView.

Comment: cool defiantly going to give that a try at some point :P cheers for the help btw

Answer (score 2):

Simply use this :

//This is the delegate method which you are missing in TableView.

```
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (section == 0){
         return @"header one";
      }

}
```

whereas if you wish to add the View in the Header or want to do the custom things, then you need to use this delegate method:

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section;
```